# Unable to fine content type by its name SharePoint online Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, content-type

I am trying to add site columns in my existing content type. Currently this content type is not associated with any lists/Library. 
I am able to find content type by it's id but I am looking for it's Name.

Thanks

Comment: please share the code that you are using , will help us identify the issue

Comment: Have you tried the script below ?

Comment: Yes..It's working fine for me...Thanks

Comment: Thanks for confirm, you could accept as answer so that it could also help others in the forum. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi Sachin, Please help to accept as answer if it is working for you. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use the script below to find content type by name:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Config Parameters
$SiteURL= "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/"
$ContentTypeName="Discussion"
$User = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"  
$Password = 'yourpassword' 
$Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))


Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Cred

    #Get content types of the web
    $ctx.Load($ctx.Web.ContentTypes)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Get the content type by its name
    $ContentType = $Ctx.Web.ContentTypes | Where {$_.Name -Match $ContentTypeName}
    $Ctx.Load($ContentType)   
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #sharepoint online get content type id
    write-host -f Green "Content Type ID:" $ContentType.Id
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Getting Content Type ID!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not say what the problem is: Are you using [PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell)?

I'd suggest you use [Get-PnPContentType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpcontenttype?view=sharepoint-ps) from [PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell). Using that you could get the ContentType by simply:

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename 
Get-PnPContentType -Identity Element # returns "Element"
Get-PnPContentType -Identity 0x01    # also returns "Element"
Get-PnPContentType                   # returns all
```

If you are not using PnP you might try [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/115518/7045) or [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/249429/7045).

Comment: HI, I am not using PnP. I am using CSOM-PoswerShell.

Comment: I updated the answer. I suggest you have a look at PnP - it extends "simple" CSOM and make life a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
param (
    [string] $siteUrl = "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com",
    [string] $username = "user@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com",
    [string] $password = 'password'
)

$SPClient = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$SPRuntime = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePass)

$ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web.ContentTypes)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


$Web.ContentTypes | ForEach-Object {

   echo $_.Name

}
```